# Caching audio Buffers to prevent decoding Audio data each time

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer, html5-audio

I am working with audio files where in I upload and each time the audio file is fetched from the server it is represented in the UI with functionality to play/pause etc. I am working with .wav/.mp3 files of duration close to about an hour.

The library I am using for displaying the waveform loads the entire audio file at once into an `audioBuffer` so streaming is out of option.

I am trying to find a way to cache the `audioBuffer` in order to skip the `decodeAudioData()` step entirely.

What I am currently doing is store the `Float32Array` representation using `audioBuffer.getChannelData(0)` method and convert back to `audioBuffer` (which almost takes the same amount of time) and using `localforage` to use indexedDB to set and get, but it has it's limitations and cannot store the `Float32Array` for large mp3 files (1hr ~ file size of about 86-100mb)

I cannot direclty store `audioBuffers` in indexedDB due to incompatibility of indexedDB to store such formats.

I need a way to skip the `decodeAudioData()` step and directly consume the `audioBuffer` of the files already loaded once.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, it may be worth caching the visual waveform once it's generated (or pre-rendering on the server).  Perhaps the visualization can be rasterized and stored as a png/jpg locally or sent from the server.  Or if it's SVG, those elements could be saved.  Or if it's canvas, perhaps the pixel matrix could be saved, which would probably use less memory than decoded audio.

One thing the `<audio>` element is good for is streaming and seeking.  The browsers do a lot of that heavy lifting for you and should balance performance optimizations without needing to fetch and decode the entire 1hr audio file.  If you could leverage the native platform features while using visual component caching, this may be a way around local cache size limitations.